How to prevent imports to minimize when I open a new file in IntelliJ?
Attached a picture of the imports when I open any new file. They are always minimized by default. How do I prevent that from happening?
This is IntelliJ, I use mostly for Java files but same goes for Typescript files as well. I think it would be applicable for all files.


I'd suggest checking your settings at Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding -- look for "Imports" options. That's the best I can think of (not using IntelliJ specifically, but another IDEA-based IDE)

@LazyOne Yeah, this worked, thanks a lot. If you post this as an answer then I will mark it as answered.

Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding -- check what you have there, "Imports" in particular.

